# Using a sharepoint datasource in .rdlc report file in VS2012

Tags: c#, sharepoint, rdlc

I'm basically banging my head against a wall here.

I've got a sharepoint list that I want as a datasource in a .rdlc file. So I go to "Add Dataset", name it, then select "New" to create a new datasource. VS walks me through creating a new datasource, then when I'm finished it shows up as a Service Reference and I can use it in code.

Now, the annoying part. It still doesn't show up in the drop-down list. It doesn't matter how many times I create the datasource or where I put the report, it refuses to acknowledge the existence of this new datasource and doesn't let me use it.

Any and all help would be appreciated here. If you need more information, let me know.